# Asking questions concerning people's opinion

Tags: discussion

Have been trawling the net trying to find decent tutorials for various parts of blender and was wondering if it is acceptable to ask on this site. I know this concerns people's opinions but was wondering if I put a specific area of blender down i.e node editing, video editing, constraints, if it would be allowed.

Comment: See this [post here](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/62/regarding-questions-and-answers-as-tutorials), this might help a bit pertaining to this site.. we also have a [beginners reference](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40/beginners-reference) post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When an area of Blender isn't clear to you, instead of looking for tutorials, look for the words needed to focus on a question about specific things. The wiki pages for the various areas in Blender are reasonably informative, but had they been perfect then sites like BlenderSE wouldn't need to exist.

You can always drop into the main blender chatroom on StackExchange ( currently) *[The RenderFarm](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8888/the-renderfarm)* to ask people about tutorials for topics. If no one is active, ask anyway and check the logs later.

You will find you learn more if you ask for fellow chatters to help you find the vocabulary needed to do your own search engine searches for tutorials.